# App release Code Sign error on xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I tried to build release version of my project for my iPHone device. (I choose Products->Archive), then I got the following error:

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: XXX' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains
```

What does it mean & How to get rid of this problem?

By the way, I opened my keychain access, and found this `iphone Distribution: xxx` under "**certificates**", it is not expired.

I googled the problem, someone said it is because my app bundle id does not match the one defined in provision file. But how can I check the bundle id defined in provision file?

Comment: Do you have any certificate installed on your machine? open keychain and look for it.

Comment: edit your mobileProvision file with TextEdit and look for "<key>application-identifier</key>" to get the ID :P

Comment: have you created the Certificate for the account this provisioning profile is made with? other way you have to get the private key to be able to sign this cert ;)

Comment: just edit your provisioning profile with your current certificate ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project->target->Build settings, change your code signing identity for release. Do the same in Project->Build settings-> Codesigning. Then clean the build and build it again.

If it is not working, close the project and open it again and build it. it will work.

Comment: Give your distribution provisioning profile here. Choose it from the list. If your not install the release profile, it wont be listed.